# React filtered array of values is not getting updated in the dropdown,however is in fact updated in console.log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have two dropdowns and the second one is being populated based on a value selected in the first one.
Once the value in the first dropdown is selected the array of options for the second dropdown is being filtered based on a value of selected option in the first dropdown.

When the app is loaded and first value is selected in the first dropdown, the options are filtered properly,however if I close the dropdown and select the same first option again,the filtered results are not being updated in the second dropdown,but they are still appearing in console.log as correct filtered result.

Here is a code example:

```
function MyForm(){

const [optValue,setOptValue] = React.useState('');

const options = [
{key:'testvalue',text:'testvalue',value:'testvalue'},
{key:'anotherTestvalue',text:'anotherTestvalue',value:'anotherTestvalue'},
]

const options2 = [
{key:'testvalue',text:'update',value:'update'},
{key:'testvalue',text:'delete',value:'delete'},
{key:'anotherTestvalue',text:'modify',value:'modify'},
{key:'anotherTestvalue',text:'create',value:'create'},
]
const filteredOptions = options2.filter(el => {
let opValue;

if (optValue == 'testvalue') {
opValue = el.key === 'testvalue'

} else if (optValue == 'anotherTestvalue') {
 opValue= el.key === 'anotherTestValue'
}

return opValue;

});

return (

<UI.Form.Field
control={Select}
options={options}
onChange={(e,{value}) => {
setOptValue(value);
}}
/>

<UI.Form.Field
control={Select}
options={filteredOptions}

/>
)
}
```

So, once I open the form and select the first value in the first dropdown,second one displays two values: update and delete.And If I select second value in the first dropdown,the second one displays two values: create,modify.However if I select the first value in the first dropdown again,the values from the second dropdown are still remaining despite the fact that the filter is working

P.S.
I'm using Semantic UI for styling of my form

Answer (score -1):

How i see is easy to fix, you need to call an useEffect who inspect the value of the first selector, then in the useEffect change data of filter and it will work properly.

```
useEffect( ()=>{
//Here call the filter function and charge it into a state to be sure
// that render will update. 
}),[optValue]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just did it but still no update